# Open-SSH Windows Bad Auth Request

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012-r2, authentication, ssh-agent

I'm trying to use OpenSSH for Windows (Server 2012 R2). I am able to authenticate (using username and password for now) however despite logging in fine it actually shows this error in the log:

> 2532 00:23:09 641 debug1: bad password auth request

I don't know what this is indicating however as I am logged in but I cannot execute any commands. Can someone inform me how I can rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's nothing to do with authentication in my case; I had incorrectly submitted the wrong command. As it's on the Windows platform, I had opted to send the 'dir' command however the correct form is 'cmd /C dir'.

I hope this helps somebody else due to the different nature of Windows and *nix systems!